# best way to edit a question where OP asked more than one question?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710616/r-addressing-a-data-frame-object-with-a-dynamic-value) the OP is asking two separate questions. The original version asked only a single question (which is actually a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-variable), but it took me a little while to find it); after getting an answer to that question, they added a new question.  Now the question has reasonable answers to both questions; the accepted answer addresses the second question only.

This is kind of a mess, what's the best thing to do?

- edit to remove the second question, encourage the user to ask the second question separately?  (Then the answer to the second question will be orphaned)
- leave the mess alone?
- close and encourage them to edit? (It's already answered, perhaps it's too late for that?)

Comment: Roll it back to the earlier version and leave a note for the OP to ask only one question per question (and explicitly encourage them to open a new question *if they have one after this question*).  You can then take any action you need to on the rolled-back question as necessary.

Comment: I've rolled it back, downvoted and VTC as duplicate, *"You are almost correct. It costs 90 minutes ;>"* being the clincher.